# Undoing demilitarized zone on router

Tags: macos, router

I set my Thomson router to forward all internet traffic to a single machine.  To do this, I connected to the router wirelessly at 192.168.1.254 and then changed the settings.  Now, I want to undo this, but 192.168.1.254 is not connecting (I think it's looking for this address on the outside world?)  How do I connect to the router wirelessly?

When I go to System Preferences, AirPort, Advanced, TCP/IP, I see that my IPV4 address is the same IP address that whatismyip.com reports, my subnet mask is 255.0.0.0, and there's an IP address for "Router".  But, navigating to router never connects.  (Of course the router is working since I have wireless internet access through it.)

Comment: write the ip addresses of routers and your machine...You might be in a different subnet...

Comment: @VineetMenon: Isn't that risky with my NAT open and no firewall?  Both my router and my machine have the same first three numbers, but a different final number.

Comment: okay....but don't worry..ur IP might not be public for someone to hack onto your system. Anyways, since your first three numbers are same It should be in same subnet, assuming your subnet mask is 255.255.255.0.

Comment: My subnet mask is 255.0.0.0, but I don't know what that means.  How should I connect to it?

Comment: You can check these things, 1. try pinging your router. If it succeeds, then mostly your router is not allowing config page access via wireless. else you cannot ping it then the subnetting might be the issue.

Comment: Pinging works fine.  So, I absolutely have to use a network cable to change the settings?

Comment: yup, I think so...try with a cable and then change the settings in router to allow wireless access for config file. But this is a security issue...you might want to consider not doing this!!

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!  Am I really at risk right now?  Should I enable my firewall?

Comment: as far as I understand your situation, its quite safe now! just remember that use LAN for router config. I cannot say anything about security of your setup from here... anyways enabling firewall is a desired feature!